# How can I access the query for my cfoutput dynamically, based on a query name variable?

Tags: dynamic, coldfusion, cfoutput

I have a struct that contains 2 queries. I have a variable with the "key" of one of the queries, and I want to output the query dynamically using that variable. My basic code:

```
<cfquery name="myQueries.names" ... >...</cfquery>
<cfquery name="myQueries.places" ... >...</cfquery>

<cfset queryName = "places" />

<cfoutput query="myQueries[queryName]">
...
</cfoutput>
```

This gives me the error `Attribute validation error for tag cfoutput.`

The cfoutput "query" attribute doesn't seem to support bracket notation. How can I access the query from the cfoutput?

Comment: I believe you can set it to another variable and use that variable as your query name. Seems silly, but should work.

Comment: `<cfset realquery = myQueries[queryName]>`

Comment: Oh wow. That did it. Not sure why I didn't think of that! Thanks.

Comment: *set it to another variable* More specifically, create an intermediary variable that has a [valid variable name](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Creating+variables).

Comment: @MattBusche, you should make that an answer so it can be marked as correct.

Comment: @mkross1983 I've posted this as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query attribute of cfoutput requires a [valid variable name](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Creating+variables), so you can set an intermediary value and use that to reference your query

```
<cfset realQuery = myQueries[queryName]>
<cfoutput query="realQuery">
...
</cfoutput>
```